# Encoding string features in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have dataframe like following

```
train_df
'type', 'manufacturer', 'year', 'num_doors'
sedan, bmw, 2012, 4
couple, audi, 2014, 2
and so on
```

and `test_df` in similar format
All the features are categorical features (some string, some int) and I want to encode them as categorical variables.

Whats a good way to handle these categorical variables in pandas/sklearn
Also, once the transformation is applied on train df.. I want to encode the test_df also as per these encodings?

Comment: Do you know what columns are categorical to begin with?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ all columns in dataframe are categorical

Comment: Even the year column?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: yeah.. though there are only 10 possible values it can take..

Comment: Look up one hot encoding and `get_dummies()` - both `sklearn` functions IIRC

Comment: @pault get_dummies() is from pandas, not scikit-learn

Comment: @Fraz Which answer were you looking for?

Answer (score 4):

When reading your data, specify `dtype` to be `category` to make *every single column* categorical in nature.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype='category')
df

     type manufacturer  year num_doors
0   sedan          bmw  2012         4
1  couple         audi  2014         2
```

```
df.dtypes

type            category
manufacturer    category
year            category
num_doors       category
dtype: object
```

If you want to convert only a specific subset of columns, something like this would do -

```
f = dict.fromkeys(['type', 'manufacturer', ...], 'categorical')
```

Pass `f` to `dtype`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=f)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

If you can use the development version of scikit (scikit-learn v0.20.dev0) , then there's a [CategoricalEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) present there, which does exactly what you want.

Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import CategoricalEncoder
enc = CategoricalEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
enc.fit(X)

enc.categories_
# Output: 
# [array(['sedan', 'couple'], dtype=object), 
   array(['bmw', 'audi'], dtype=object)]
   array([2012, 2014], dtype=object)]
   ... 
   ...
```

If you are unable to use that and want to use the current stable version (<=0.19.1), then you have to use a combination of LabelEncoder + OneHotEncoder to do the same.

- LabelEncoder to convert the strings to numerical
- OneHotEncoder to one hot encode the numerical data. (OHE dont work with strings)

The above two work well where you have data split into train and test already.

But if you have all the data at once, then the recommended way is to use [get_dummies() from pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), after which you can split the data into train and test.

**Update**:

Apparently, `CategoricalEncoder` has been removed from scikit and `OneHotEncoder` has been given those capabilities. So in current dev version, `OneHotEncoder` can do string to one-hot encoding directly, without using `LabelEncoder`.