# Sklearn models for animal classification

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**Edits:**
So I managed to fix the errors with all the suggestions. But now at the model.predict part is is giving me this issue.

```
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[   12 15432    40    20    33 40000 12800    20 19841     0     0].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a 
single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Here is the new code that I am using

```
'''
This method is to handel the training and testing of the models
'''
def testTrainModel(model, xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest):
    print("Start Method")
    print("Traing Model")
    model.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
    print("Model Trained")
    print("testing models")
    results = model.predict(xTest)

    print(model.__class__," Prediction Report")
    print(classification_report(results,yTest))
    print("Confusion Matrix")
    print(confusion_matrix(results,yTest))
    print("Accuracy is ", accuracy_score(results, yTest)*100)
    lables =["Hunter", "Scavenger"]
    plotConfusionMatrix(confusion_matrix(results,yTest),
                    lables,
                     title='Confusion matrix')

#Data set Preprocess data
dataframe = pd.read_csv("animalData.csv", dtype = 'category')
print(dataframe.head())
dataframe = dataframe.drop(["Name"], axis = 1)
cleanup = {"Class": {"Primary Hunter" : 0, "Primary Scavenger": 1 }}
dataframe.replace(cleanup, inplace = True)
print(dataframe.head())

#array = dataframe.values
#Data splt
# Seperating the data into dependent and independent variables
X = dataframe.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataframe.iloc[:,-1].values
#Get training and testoing data

#Set up the models Put model nicknake and model
models = []
models.append(('LogReg', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('DecTree', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))

#Create all the models
logReg = LogisticRegression()
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
decsTree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
nb = GaussianNB()
svm = SVC()

#Test value
trex = [12,15432,40,20,33,40000,12800,20,19841,0,0,0]
testTrainModel(logReg,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(lda,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(knn,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(decsTree,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(nb,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(svm,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
```

**OLD:**
What I am trying to do here is to use a list of animal characteristics like teeth and size, then use a couple of built in model like SVN KNN ect with  this cvs data set that I made. But it keeps saying that it cannot convert string to float, when I take out all the strings in the cvs it does work but I dont know if it is what I want as I want to plot each animal as either a hunter or scavenger. I really dont know what I am doing wrong here as I am new to python. Maybe some one could help with this and look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong here. Also any suggestion to improve this would be happily accepted.

So my code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report


def plotConfusionMatrix(cm, classes,
                      normalize=False,
                      title='Confusion matrix',
                      cmap=plt.cm.Blues):

plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
plt.title(title)
plt.colorbar()
tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
thresh = cm.max() / 2.
for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
    plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
             horizontalalignment="center",
             color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()

'''
This method is to handel the training and testing of the models
'''
def testTrainModel(model, xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest):
    print("Start Method")
    print("Traing Model")
    model.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
    print("Model Trained")
    print("testing models")
    results = model.predict(xTest)

    print(model.__class__," Prediction Report")
    print(classification_report(results,yTest))
    print("Confusion Matrix")
    print(confusion_matrix(results,yTest))
    print("Accuracy is ", accuracy_score(results, yTest)*100)
    lables =["Hunter", "Scavenger"]
    plotConfusionMatrix(confusion_matrix(results,yTest),
                        lables,
                         title='Confusion matrix')




#T-Rex, 12, 15432,  40, 20, 33, 40000,  12800,  20, 19841,  0,  0,


#Data set
dataframe = pd.read_csv("animalData.csv")
print(dataframe.head())
#array = dataframe.values
#Data splt
# Seperating the data into dependent and independent variables
X = dataframe.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataframe.iloc[:,-1].values
#Get training and testoing data

seed = 7 #prepare configuration for cross validation test harness

#Set up the models Put model nicknake and model
models = []
models.append(('LogReg', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('DecTree', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))


#store the results
results = []
names =[]
scoring = 'accuracy'
#print the results

for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=9, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kfold,             scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "Model:%s:\n Cross Validation Score Mean:%f - StdDiv:(%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)

#plot the data
figure1 = plt.figure()
figure1.suptitle("Algorithm Comparision")
ax = figure1.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()

#Create all the models
logReg = LogisticRegression()
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
decsTree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
nb = GaussianNB()
svm = SVC()

#Test value
trex = ["T-Rex",12,15432,40,20,33,40000,12800,20,19841,0,0,"Primary Hunter"]
testTrainModel(logReg,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(lda,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(knn,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(decsTree,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(nb,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
testTrainModel(svm,X, y, trex[:-1], trex[-1:])
```

Now this is doing a lot and I think I am getting everything out right but may be my data is wrong as well.

Here is the test csv file

> Name,teethLength,weight,length,hieght,speed,Calorie Intake,Bite Force,Prey Speed,PreySize,EyeSight,Smell,Class
>   Crocodile,4,2400,23,1.6,8,2500,3700,30,881,0,0,Primary Hunter
>   Lion,2.7,416,9.8,3.9,50,7236,650,35,1300,0,0,Primary Hunter
>   Bear,3.6,600,7,3.35,40,20000,975,0,0,0,0,Primary Scavenger
>   Tiger,3,260,12,3,40,7236,1050,37,160,0,0,Primary Hunter
>   Hyena,0.27,160,5,2,37,5000,1100,20,40,0,0,Primary Scavenger
>   Jaguar,2,220,5.5,2.5,40,5000,1350,15,300,0,0,Primary Hunter
>   Cheetah,1.5,154,4.9,2.9,70,2200,475,56,185,0,0,Primary Hunter
>   KomodoDragon,0.4,150,8.5,1,13,1994,240,24,110,0,0,Primary Scavenger

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Stack Trace

```
  File "<ipython-input-10-691557e6b9ae>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('E:/TestPythonCode/Classifier.py', wdir='E:/TestPythonCode')

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "E:/TestPythonCode/Classifier.py", line 110, in <module>
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 342, in cross_val_score
pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 206, in cross_validate
for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
result = ImmediateResult(func)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
self.results = batch()

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 458, in _fit_and_score
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1216, in fit
    order="C")

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 573, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)

  File "C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\TensorfGPU2\lib\site-    packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'KomodoDragon'
```

Comment: can you please paste your stack trace as well, like in which line it's occurring.

Comment: Please perform one hot encoding on columns containing words and strings.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @MNM  `print(data.info())` The columns which are `string` or `object` type. Convert them.
`label encode` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html
`one hot encode` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Scikit learn classifiers only works with numerical data. So if you have string data in your columns, you need to transform them using some pre-processing. That pre-processing varies according to the type of data you have. For example, on text data, you can do tokenization and then tf-idf or frequency counts. For ordinal data (where the words define some kind of order - high, medium, low), encode them to numbers appropriately (put 3 = high, 2=medium, 1=low). For data which have no order and only represent categories (as in your case), you should do one-hot encoding as @ArsalanAhmed suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoding string features in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273112/encoding-string-features-in-pandas)

Comment: for the latest error, you should use 2d array for test data `trex = np.array([[12,15432,40,20,33,40000,12800,20,19841,0,0,0]])`

Comment: I tried that and this

trex = np.array([[12,15432,40,20,33,40000,12800,20,19841,0,0,0]])
trex = trex.reshape(1,-1)
But it still gives me the same issues

Answer (score 1):

if you are using numpy.ndarry, it's invalid using string element and float element together.For example:
a native python list:

`mylist = [1, 3, 'KomodoDragon']`

it's ok, but when you try to convert list mylist to a ndarry object, like:

```
mylist = np.array(mylist, dtype=float)
```

an error will occur

> could not convert string to float: 'KomodoDragon'

.
you can use one-hot encoding to handle this issue.

Comment: tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))  this is the only place that I am using np. Did I do that with dataframes?

Comment: When I print the dataframe it looks fine